# Electric potential inside a conducting shell having some width

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, coordinate-systems

First, explain that whether or not the electric potential inside a shell is equal to the potential in the surface of the shell? And if the shell boundary has some width as the inner surface radius is $'a'$(let) and the other surface has radius $'b'$(let). Then if we are given the electric field in terms of $\rho$(the volume charge density of the shell), then how will I put the limits of integration to find the potential at the center? Whether I should integrate from $'b'$ to $'a'$ or from $'a'$ to $'b'$?

Second, if I was given the volume charge density of a shell having some width then can I find the potential inside the shell(at the center) by using the Laplace's equation($\vec \nabla^2$V = $-\rho/\epsilon_0$)?

Please tell me whether coordinate system while integrating matters or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) The electric field is zero inside the shell, so the potential will be constant. In particular, it will be equal to the potential on the surface of the shell.

2) The order of the limits of integration is irrelevant, since a minus sign will appear on both sides of the equation
$$
\int_{\gamma} \mathbf{E} \cdot d\mathbf{s} = -(V(\gamma^{(1)}) - V(\gamma^{(0)})) 
$$
where $\gamma^{(0)}, \gamma^{(1)}$ are the "extrema" of the curve along which you are integrating.

3) The solutions of $\nabla^2 V = -\frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}$ can be obtained using different coordinate systems. For instance, in spherical coordinates you obtain solutions that involve Legendre polynomials. However, finding the right coordinate system for the specific problem you are trying to solve can make things a bit easier.